# Would this be an on-topic question here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, stackoverflow

I asked this question on SO, but it's likely going to be closed for being OT. Would it be on topic here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574155/notable-electronic-systems-that-dont-have-a-cpu-or-other-programmable-part

Comment: Thank you for asking on meta before asking on main.  No, that's not likely to be on-topic here as it essentially boils down to being a poll.   A better place to ask that question would be chat.